# Using Python to automate web-based processing?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm trying to use Python to automatically upload, submit, and retrieve files on websites that do sequence processing.

Example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Structure/bwrpsb/bwrpsb.cgi

Does anyone know the best way to do this, whether it be specific modules or tutorials? Would this work with the requests module? Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example looks like an older system but if at all possible, I would suggest adding automating via an API due to your "retrieval" requirements prior to considering [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

However, if you find yourself using Python with Selenium Webdriver, save yourself some setup effort and check out [SeleniumBase](https://seleniumbase.io/).

Also, something worth checking out if there is a budget associated with this project and you want vendor support, [UiPath RPA](https://www.uipath.com/rpa/robotic-process-automation).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I'm not sure there is an API compatible for this website, so I'll try using Selenium first.

Comment: Sounds good, check out SeleniumBase which will save you time on setting up selenium to work with python. It's worth noting that you want to limit the number of steps in the tests that you're writing so that they're not breaking and considered "flaky"

Comment: Great, I'll definitely check it out! Do you know of a way to have it be cross-platform rather than make a new webdriver each time? This is part of a larger project that's meant for a large audience, so something like that would be great. I saw a post using the pyautogui module, but I'm not really sure how to get everything set up.

Comment: Sure, with selenium you can download individual binaries e.g. geckodriver, chromedriver, etc. but it's worth noting that SeleniumBase will provide this for you so you don't have to spend a ton of time with setting things up to work (which can be a pain). So, that's your cross-browser coverage.

Regarding cross-platform, you may want to checkout running Selenium Grid in docker containers. There are managed versions of this, such as SauceLabs, BrowserStack, etc.

Hope this helps,

Comment: For SeleniumBase, is there a way to define the class and methods and run it in the same script rather than using the command line? Thanks!

Comment: Something page object related? Reference: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/ not sure if I am reading the question correctly, this video might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sjzq9kU5kOw -- you can add tests like you normally would with Python + Selenium

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, and thank you for providing the resources. I meant to ask if there was a way to define the class and then run the test without going into the command line and entering "pytest File.py ..." or nosetests, as in run the methods kind of as though it were just a normal function in the main program.

Comment: if you want to run all of the tests instead of one like you specified above you will use the command pytest some-directory/ (this will execute any tests by discovering them via test_*.py or *_test.py

you can read more about that here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/getting-started.html (seleniumbase uses pytest)

let me know if this helps otherwise I'll keep my eye on this thread

Comment: Makes sense – thanks again. So for each class I define, if they're not meant to be executed right after one another, I would need to write each in a different file, and call then separately using pytest?

Comment: yeah, you could do something like that. If you want to execute specific groups of tests you could use something called a marker in pytest/seleniumbase. 

Something like this "-m=MARKER  # Run tests with the specified pytest marker." Where "-m=uploadfile" or whatever you add there. There are various ways to break your tests up but in your scenario you might want to look at multiple step tests where it runs through the entire scenario.

In the past I would design tests for specific pages on a site and group those in directories and execute the directory or markers via a CI/CD server

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

You can use it in different web browsers.

As the task is sequence processing it should be simple.
Regards!!!